# Project Oxford - HTTP 404 when calling Computer Vision API through Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to get JSON data from Microoft Project Oxford through a API call. I followed [the](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/54ef139a49c3f70a50e79b7d/operations/550a323849c3f70b34ba2f8d) API reference but when I make a call I get a 404 error.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var params = {
                // Request parameters
                "visualFeatures": "All",
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/analyses&" + $.param(params),
                beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","0000000000000000");
                },
                type: "POST",
                // Request body
                data: '{ "Url": "http://www.sweetheartmotors.ca/sites/default/files/audi_PNG1736.png" }',
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("success");

                //display data
                console(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("error");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

What is stopping me from making the call?

Comment: Try Firefox or host your webapp on a local webserver.

Comment: I just created a index.html file and copied the contents on it there, than ran if off Chrome. I don't understand how running client side code is relevant to using a server

Comment: I'm not convinced it's an error in your code, you get the same response if you visit that URL directly: https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/analyses&visualFeatures=All

Comment: … and 404 isn't an expected error according to their docs (if the issue was the data, it should be a 400 error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the URL to end in a question mark, rather than an ampersand: `https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/analyses?`

Unfortunately most of the samples on the projectoxford.ai site contain this error.

Comment: It still gives me a 404 when I enter the url https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/analyses?visualFeatures=All. Rather than an error message saying you are missing arguments

Comment: You will get a 404 if you merely enter that address in the browser, since that is an HTTP GET, whereas the API is expecting a POST.  I tried your sample, replaced the ampersand (and the API key too, of course) and it worked like a charm.